# Content Security "Refused to load media" error in Chrome Extension (manifest v3)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a Chrome Extension that when clicked inserts a video on the page:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://example.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

When using the extension on Twitter.com, the video doesn't load on the page and in the console I see this error:

```
Refused to load media from 'https://example.com/video.mp4' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' blob:
```

In `Manifest.json` (version3) I've tried several versions of the below but nothing works. Does anyone know how to resolve this error so that the video can load? Any and all help is much appreciated - thanks.

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; media-src * blob: https://example.com/*"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't insert a `<video>` tag into page protected by CSP. Twitter has a CSP with:

```
media-src 'self' blob: https://*.vine.co https://*.giphy.com
   https://media.riffsy.com https://*.twimg.com https://twitter.com
   https://dhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net
   https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net
   https://pdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://dwo3ckksxlb0v.cloudfront.net
   https://*.pscp.tv https://*.video.pscp.tv;
```

and as you can see it's a twitter's CSP blocks you extension's work:

> Refused to load media from `'https://example.com/video.mp4'` because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "**media-src 'self' blob: ...**

Because your extension's CSP is `media-src * blob: https://example.com/*"` - these are not the rules that you see blocked in the console.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; media-src * blob: https://example.com/*"
```

try:

```
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; media-src example.com"
```

Comment: Thanks @ste-xx - unfortunately the issue is still occurring. I wonder if the problem is that i'm trying to do this on Twitter.com? Perhaps they're the ones blocking the request and not my extension?

Answer (score 0):

As @granty mentioned there's no direct solution given Twitter prohibitive CSP.

A workaround however is to insert an iframe on the page and insert insert the video in the iframe. Hope this helps anyone else looking for a solution!

Comment: Twitter's CSP was made by pros. The `frame-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com/ https://twitter.com https://cards-frame.twitter.com https://mobile.twitter.com https://pay.twitter.com;` rule puts an end to your workaround.